# If $A\in\Bbb R^{3\times3}$ is an invertible matrix such that $A^2=A$, then $\det(2A)=8$

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, determinant

True or false?

**"If $\pmb{A\in\Bbb R^{3\times3}}$ is an invertible matrix such that $\pmb{A^2=A}$, then $\pmb{\det(2A)=8}$".**

---

True.

*Proof.* We start from $\det(2A)$. Then, $2^3\det(A)$. But we know that $A^2=AA=A$, so $A=AA^{-1}$ because $A$ is an invertible matrix, hence $$8\det(A)=8\det(AA^{-1})=8\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=8\det(A)(\det(A))^{-1}=8\det(A)\frac{1}{\det(A)}=8,$$ which is where we wanted to go.  $\square$

**Is it correct?**

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good, but long! Here $A=AA^{-1}=I$, so  $$\det(2A)=2^3 \det(A)=2^3\det(I)=8$$

**Moral:** The only matrix which is both idempotent and invertible is the identity matrix !

Comment: Yes and thanks! That's because $A^2-A=A(A-I)=0$, so $A=0$ (absurd because $A$ is invertible), hence $A=I$, and $\det(I)=1$?

Comment: In general. $AB=0$ does not imply $A=0$ or $B=0$. Here $A^2-A=0$ implies the minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$ divides $x^2-x=x(x-1)$. but  $A$ is invertible so $m_A(x)$ cannot be $x$ and so $m_A(x)=x-1$, concluding $A=I$

Comment: If you don't know what a "minimal polynomial" is, you can also note that $$\begin{align}A^2 &= A \\ \Rightarrow A^2 A^{-1} &= AA^{-1}\\ \Rightarrow A &= I.\end{align}$$ Or, from your equation $A(A-I)=O$, multiply both sides on the left by $A^{-1}$.

Comment: You don’t need to invoke minimal polynomials here. From $A^2=A$ we have $\det(A)^2=\det(A)$, therefore $\det(A)=0$ or $\det(A)=1$.

Comment: @amd: Agree and thanks!